# Server Side API for Mobile Applications

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile

I am an iPhone developer. I create many mobile applications. Some of them need a server side backend to store data and then my iPhone applications access them.

Usually, I need to create a backend web application myself using PHP or RoR. However, they are very straight forward web application with some cruds (create, update, delete, edit, ..etc)

There are some troubles with this work:

1. I need to create very simple application and deploy it myself to the
   server
2. If I am only iPhone developer and don't know PHP or RoR, I
   ask for some other web developer help.

Is there any existing web application that enables me to build my database schema and just give me API access to my data?

Comment: So what did you finally go with? Did it make your work easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at [parse.com](https://www.parse.com/), it provides you the facility to add back-end to your mobile applications in minutes. Here is a [tour](https://www.parse.com/tour) of their services and [android guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#data).

Comment: It seems parse doesn't have tables relations-ships (1-M,..etc)

Comment: @MahmoudKhaled Through parse you can maintain relationships. You can even maintain (1-M)relationships in parse.For example 1 post may contain many comments. Look at this link https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers.

Comment: @MahmoudKhaled yep, not from data browser, but you can create a new data browser yourself considering table relationships ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to recommend [Appacitive](http://appacitive.com/) - Its an awesome tool with many innovative features. One of the biggest advantage it has is that you can create your data model diagrammatically, and all the corresponding APIs are automatically generated for you.

They have relationship managers both in diagrammatic designer and via code. You can also filter data by using their visual tools. Test drive the APIs via their Test Harness tool.

Other great features include a data explorer, inbuilt Social Integration and Geo Location. Have a look at their [features](http://appacitive.com/features/).

Try out their [free package](http://appacitive.com/pricing/), they have all sorts of SDKs for Javascript, Android, iOS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com). There is [Custom Objects module](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects), it allows to to build any data structure you want. There are a lot of [iOS samples](http://quickblox.com/developers/Category%3aIOS)